# Customizing ivp in scipy, where to control each step size in Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

The question is related to `ivp` function in `scipy` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

If one loads a Runge-Kutta method, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods
the RK4 example, in each step `h`, there are `s` smaller steps calling `f` and solve the difference. My question is, take the below Python code for example (modified from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp)
where to customize after each `h`?

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def exponential_decay(t, y): 
    print(t)
    return -0.5 * y

sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 3], [2, 4, 8], method = 'DOP853')

print(sol.t)
```

I will get

```
0.0
0.02
0.022975306924280958
0.03446296038642143
0.09190122769712383
0.10211247521902646
0.11487653462140478
0.11487653462140478
0.3446296038642143
0.4595061384856191
1.033888811592643
1.1360012868116693
1.2636418808354524
1.2636418808354524
1.6109135046683618
1.7845493165848167
2.6527283761670906
2.807071320092828
3.0
3.0
[0.         0.11487653 1.26364188 3.        ]
```

looks like `[0.         0.11487653 1.26364188 3.        ]` is `h` and `0.0 0.02 0.022975306924280958...`  is `t_n + c_s h`.

If I want to do some additional setup after each `h`, (not each `t_t + c_s h`), e.g., print  hello world at  0.11487653 1.26364188 3.,    how to do?

look for wikipedia and provide an example;
expect e.g., print hello world after each $h$

Comment: The solvers in scipy.integrate are all variable-step methods, while RK4 and the wikipedia methods are usually used as fixed-step methods. // What you want is not built-in into the solve_ivp time loop. You could copy that code and extend it or make a simpler time loop with the RK45 class and its step method.

Comment: You can probably extend the use of the event mechanism to report on the values after every step. Return a non-zero constant. This has only a copy of the state available, it can not change the state of the solver.

Comment: Does `Julia` has package support this type of functionalities?

Comment: I think so. The Julia library has a multitude of observer and action mechanisms. But start again with the purpose of your question. There is almost never a good reason to trace the internal steps. Most often you can do the same without changing the user experience by evaluating the value table in the result (when not using the `t_eval` parameter). If you want to change the integration due to some condition on the state, use the event mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean by some "setup" at certain steps?

Comment: e.g., print hello world at 0.11487653 1.26364188 3., sorry for the confusing @jared